# Construction tree

Tags: java, tree

I wrote a tree construction method. I don't see any errors when running it. However, when I'm testing the tree if it is symmetric or not and should return false (for input: [1,2,2,4,4, null, 6]) This means that I am putting root node as 1, second level: 2,2 third level: 4, 4, null, 6. It is returning true. I'm not sure what's wrong? I'm sure that my symmetric function is correct, I just don't know what's wrong with my tree construction? I tried debugging and I saw all the values in the array were implemented in the construction. Can someone let me know what's going on?

```
public class isSymmetric {
    public static class TreeNode {
        public int key;
        public TreeNode left;
        public TreeNode right;

        public TreeNode(int key) {
            this.key = key;
            this.left = this.right = null;
        }
    }
    public boolean symmetric(TreeNode root) {
        ...
    }

    //Tree test cases
    public static TreeNode construction(Integer[] array) {
        //use level order traversal to construct a tree
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(array[0]);
        return constructionhelp(array, root, 0);

    }
    public static TreeNode constructionhelp(Integer[] array, TreeNode root, int i) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (i < array.length) {
            root = new TreeNode(array[i]);
            root.left = constructionhelp(array, root.left, 2*i+1);
            root.right = constructionhelp(array, root.right, 2*i+2);
        }
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isSymmetric s = new isSymmetric();
        Integer a[] = {1,2,2,4,4,null,6};
        TreeNode roota = construction(a);
        System.out.print(s.symmetric(roota));

        }
    }
   //returning true;
```

Comment: This seriously looks like some assignment and you are asking us to solve the problem for you. Please explain better what you want to do and what you have so far (the `public boolean symmetric` method)

Comment: I am implementing this on my own. the symmetric returns if the input tree is a symmetric tree or not. I didn't write it here because I am sure it's correct. I don't want others to be focusing on the method.

Comment: I'm not trying for anyone to implement/look at the symmetric method. And I deliberately not write it for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens:

```
root = new TreeNode(array[i]); // you create new tree node instance
root.left = constructionhelp(array, root.left, 2*i+1); // root.left is null
root.right = constructionhelp(array, root.right, 2*i+2) // root.right is null
```

so after you call your `constructionhelp` again, you pass `null` as an argument of the node.

-> `null` is returned.

-> your tree is only the root.

Comment: That make sense. How should I set root.left as the 2*I+1 index then? Should I do something as root.left = constructionhelp(array, root.key, 2*i+1) ? where I set root.left as the key value of the root?

Comment: Well you create new root, so that's not that big of a deal, but yes, you lose your original instance, which is kind of a waste. Your tree is not null, it's only the root node with left and right children being null. I don't know what you mean by "dummy for linked list", but I'd suggest creating instances of left and right children before passing them as arguments, so they are not null-s.